# Where python creates files

Tags: python, file, directory

When I make a file in python, using the following command:

```
NewFile = open('pactice1.txt','w')
```

in what directory is it created?

Comment: Have you tried the command and looked around your directories?

Answer (score 1):

[Document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)¶
```

> Open file and return a corresponding file object. If the file cannot
>   be opened, an OSError is raised.
>
> file is a path-like object giving the pathname (**absolute or relative
>   to the current working directory**) of the file to be opened or an
>   integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped. (If a file
>   descriptor is given, it is closed when the returned I/O object is
>   closed, unless closefd is set to False.)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the current working directory (of a session or script) with

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

If `NewFile` is still around (even if closed)

```
os.path.abspath(NewFile.name)
```

gives the full path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

In the same directory from where you are executing this script.

If you are not running this one from command line - then try to print current working directory using methods from "os" module.